# performance issues with xslt processing

Tags: xslt

i have parent and child tag structure, and needs to iterates the child's of parent tag and set the value in new format.

Attributes can repeated for both parent and child tags.

We need to check if the value/tag is present in child then take it otherwise take it from parent tag.

Here is the sample xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<item>
  <perishable-indicator >N</perishable-indicator>
  <product-shelf-security-type >ST - SMALL TOY</product-shelf-security-type>
  <before-date>2012-05-30</before-date>
  <partnumber>2</partnumber>
  <season>BASIC SEASON</season>
  <variant>
   <partnumber>4</partnumber>
   <season>BASIC SEASON</season>
   <division-code>055</division-code>
   <department-code>013</department-code>
   <class-code>089</class-code>
  </variant>
</item>
```

and here is the sample XSLT am using to iterate both parent and child:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/> 
<xsl:template match="item">
<Product>
    <xsl:variable name="productperishable" select="perishable-indicator"/>
    <xsl:variable name="productsecurity-type" select="product-shelf-security-type"/>
    <xsl:variable name="productbefore-date" select="before-date"/>
    <xsl:variable name="productpartnumber" select="partnumber"/>
    <xsl:variable name="productseason" select="season"/>
<xsl:for-each select="variant">
<sku>
 <xsl:choose>
 <xsl:when test="partnumber">
 <PartNumber><xsl:value-of select="partnumber"/></PartNumber>
 </xsl:when>
 <xsl:when test="$productpartnumber!=''">                       
 <PartNumber><xsl:value-of select="$productpartnumber"/></PartNumber>                       
 </xsl:when>
 </xsl:choose>
<xsl:choose>
 <xsl:when test="perishable-indicator">
 <PartNumber><xsl:value-of select="perishable-indicator"/></PartNumber>
 </xsl:when>
 <xsl:when test="$productperishable!=''">                       
 <Perishable><xsl:value-of select="$productperishable"/></Perishable>                       
 </xsl:when>
 </xsl:choose>
</sku>
</xsl:for-each>
</Product>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But if we need to iterate several items and variants present in input xml, the conversion process is taking huge time.Any input will be of great help.

Comment: Can you please explain what your XSLT is doing here? I can see the `when` conditions only on `partnumber` and `perishable-indicator`.. is it only about these two elements?

Comment: that is just an example for two elements, we have almost 40-50 elements for both parent and child tags.

Comment: you said you've to iterate several `items`.. I could see only 1 `item`(the root element) in your XML.. Can you please depict the real time scenario.

Comment: sorry, but it will be difficult me to paste entire content, the scenario is that there will be multiple <item> tag and each <item> will have multiple <variants>

Comment: @Ravi: What's your actual XML file size? There is nothing terribly strange in your XSL file that would justify huge processing time.

Comment: xml file size is approx 3GB

Comment: Any processing of a 3Gb input file is going to take a while. How long is it taking, and how long do you expect it to take? And what XSLT processor are you using? - performance questions can't be answered without knowing the specific processor.

Comment: Nothing to do with performance, but in XSLT 2.0 your code can be written in a much more concise way. e.g. `<sku><PartNumber><xsl:value-of select='(partnumber, ../partnumber)[1]'/><Perishable>...</Perishable>...</sku>`

Answer (score 0):

The coding technique shown will execute long time because the XSLT engine is forced to used the coded loops, instead of using the built in rendering engine, and many values are first copied to a variable instead of immediately copied to the output stream.

Note the xslt rendering engine will loop all elements automatically when using another coding technique. Think about XSLT as a specification to a rendering engine rather than a programming language. In this coding technique the `<xsl:apply-templates>` (rather then the `<xsl:for-each`>) tells the rendering engine to continue with whatever XML tags it will encounter in its actual context.

The default XSLT template creates an exact copy of the input:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
       <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|*">
       <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
       </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As you can see there is no `<xsl:for-each>` command in this stylesheet. You could create a compiled XSLT rendering with this spec and check for yourself the difference in runtimes.

Now you can add the transformation templates.

If I understand your spec correctly you'd like to add

```
<xsl:template match="item">
   <Product>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="variant"/>
   </Product>   
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="variant">
   <sku>
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="partnumber != ''">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="partnumber"/>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="../partnumber"/>
         </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="perishable-indicator!= ''">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="perishable-indicator"/>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="../perishable-indicator"/>
         </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
   </sku>   
</xsl:template>
```

This should cover the basics. Compile an xslt processor with this spec and let me know if this renders faster than your current process.

Next to be exactly compatible with your output spec you should create two more formatting templates to rename the generated tags:

```
<xsl:template match="partnumber">
   <PartNumber>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </PartNumber>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="perishable-indicator">
   <Perishable>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </Perishable>
</xsl:template>
```

This creates the output

```
<document>
   <Product>
      <sku>
         <PartNumber>4</PartNumber>
         <Perishable>N</Perishable>
      </sku>
   </Product>
</document>
```